# Meanings of 'killing moon' and 'killing time' in song by Echo and The Bunnymen   

Tags: meaning, expressions, lyrics

I was wondering what the meanings of the expressions *killing moon* and *killing time* on the song *Killing moon* by Echo and The Bunnymen are.

> Under blue moon I saw you So soon
>   you'll take me Up in your arms Too
>   late to beg you or cancel it Though I
>   know it must be the killing time
>   Unwillingly mine
>
> ...
>
> In starlit nights I saw you So cruelly
>   you kissed me Your lips a magic world
>   Your sky all hung with jewels The
>   killing moon Will come too soon

I assume the song does not refer to some sort of ritualistic murder on full moon. What then are the meanings intended for these expressions?

Comment: Guissing here... Killing time is normally associated with something you do when you are bored or waiting for something to happen... "We were killing time between games by drinking heavily" - here are some other takes: http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/16866/

Comment: @mplungjan: _The killing time_ is different from _we were killing time_; in the first phrase, _killing_ is adjective.

Comment: I realised that after reading the comments in the link I gave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that there are several word-plays going on here.  In American myth and folklore, the full moon of each month is given a name, such as Wolf Moon, Storm Moon, Harvest Moon, Hunter's Moon, etc. A *blue moon* is a rare occurrence that happens about once every 2-3 years when a single season (three months) experiences four full moons; the third full moon in a season with four full moons is called the *Blue Moon*.  [There is no full moon specifically called *the Killing Moon*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvest_moon#Other_names)

An Old Testament poem tells us that there is a time for everything under the sun; a time to give, a time to take, a time to heal, and a time to kill, etc.  Calling something a *killing time* or *killing moon* would mean that somebody's or something's death is imminent and unavoidable.

Comment: The blood moon, or [hunter's moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter%27s_moon), might be considered a "killing moon."

Answer (score 5):

The song is about the conflict between personal striving and inevitability, particularly the inevitability of death; the figures of the killing time and the killing moon are used to suggest death as something that occurs at a preordained moment.

Comment: So it could mean something that will occur at some point in time and there no avoiding it?

Comment: @Raphael: I'm saying it means specifically that any given person's death will occur at some point in time and there's no avoiding it.

Answer (score 3):

*Killing moon* sounds vaguely astrological, as if some alignment or what-have-you in the heavens is being interpreted as related to killing.

Alternatively, *moon* sometimes means "month".

Answer (score 2):

*Killing moon* might make perfect sense to a werewolf.

Answer (score 1):

I always felt it was about an arranged marriage, the Sitar playing makes me feel like an Indian girl is being given up to an Indian groom and the "killing Time" is when she gives up her virginity and she cannot change the fact that she really does not want this. "Up against her will" "You will wait until you give yourself to him" He will take her with a cruel kiss, because she has no say in it.